# ROSE ovun.sample -- Error: response variable has only one class

Tags: r

I have a training dataset ('tr') with a response variable named 'code' which has the response distribution seen below

```
tr %>% group_by(code) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(perc = n / sum(n))
```

| code | n | perc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| < chr > | < dbl > | < dbl > |
| 0 | 960 | 0.96 |
| 1 | 40 | 0.04 |

When I try to run the ovun.sample() function in the ROSE package, I get an error message stating that my response variable only has one class, despite there clearly being two (very unevenly distributed) classes.

See below for the code I'm using in the ovun.sample() function.

```
ovun.sample(code~.,
            data = tr,
            method = 'both',
            p = 0.5,
            seed = 111)$data
```

Why am I getting this error? I have tried changing the code column to numeric, but that didn't help. I have also tried lowering the p value, but the error remains.

Comment: Is it possible that the other variables in your data have missing values?  In general, you would get better help if you include a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you -- one of my columns had NA values in it.